# how update a field cakephp

Tags: cakephp, set, field

How I can update a field of one table, my model is called User, and I want to change the 
field 'enable'.
I do this.

```
function setstatus($id = null)
{
    $this->User->id = $id;
    if (!$this->User->exists())
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid User', 'error');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }

    $valor = false;
    $enable = $this->User->read('enable');
    if ($enable == false)
        $valor = true;

    $this->User->saveField('enable', $valor);
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            $this->Session->setFlash('User update success', 'info');
}
```

But this dont work fine.
No change the field. Please Help me...
I use Cakephp 2.3 if don't know how do that in cakephp 2.3 maybe is like cakephp 1.3.

Comment: You should not redirect before you try to write to the session...^^

Comment: does enable field is created after models are generated.?? if yes then clear temp files and clear cache..this will solve it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer myself, the solution is to take the return values from `$this->ModelName->read(field);` as an `array ['model']['field']`

Here's the code:

```
function setstatus($id = null)
{
    $this->User->id = $id;
    if (!$this->User->exists())
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid user', 'error');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'administration'));
    }

    $enable= $this->User->read('enable');
    $msj = 'The user has been enabled';
    if ($enable['User']['enable'] == 1)
    {
        $enable= 0;
        $msj = 'The user is no longer enable';
    }
    else
        $enable= 1;

    $this->User->saveField('enable', $enable);
    $this->Session->setflash($msj, 'info');
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'administration'));
}
```

Comment: @j0k Hi, I just translate it. Please check it, and let me know if it makes sense...